# How do you get the image component of a nested game object in a UI prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-gui

I am trying to alter the sprite of a nested image object within a dialog UI (Unity 4.6's UI) that I have saved as a prefab. I am able to load the prefab, but when I try to do:

```
Image[] imageComponents = conversationDialogNoChoice.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
```

I get zero items back. The hierarchy is:

[image]

The full code is:

```
        private GameObject conversationDialogNoChoice;
public void StartConversation(Conversation conversation)
    {
        if (!talking)
        {
            //StartCoroutine(DisplayConversation(conversation));
            StartCoroutine(DisplayConversation(conversation));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DisplayConversationNewUI(Conversation conversation)
    {
        conversationDialogNoChoice = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Prefabs/ConversationDialogNoChoices");
        conversationDialogChoice = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Prefabs/ConversationDialogChoices");
        ConversationTest = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Prefabs/ConversationTest");
        bool nextPushed;

        foreach (var conversationLine in conversation.ConversationLines)
        {
            nextPushed = false;
            Image[] imageComponents = conversationDialogNoChoice.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
            Debug.Log(imageComponents.Length);
            //imageComponents[].sprite = currentCovnersationLine.DisplayPicture;

            Instantiate(conversationDialogNoChoice);

            while (!nextPushed)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
                {
                    nextPushed = true;
                }
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        talking = false; //talking is complete
        if (conversation.Repeatable == false)
        {
            conversation.CanOccur = false;
        }
        yield return null;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your Image game object is active? [`GetComponentsInChildren` has `includeInactive` parameter, and it's set to `false` by default](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html).

Comment: I have a GameObject obj: obj > Canvas > ImageMask > Image > text > Image(1) > image(2). There is a "nested" or "layering" of images in one GameObject. Say I want to access just the second image, "image (1)"-of-3 images. And with this image, turn it on and off so that the other images appear. Rather than load/unload images, turning off images would seem more efficient, that is if you were wondering, why do this? In Flash it was as ease as "Frame(2) turn off".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider including "Panel" in your resource loading path.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what "Max Yankov" said.

`Image` in `GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()` refers to a script or component on the GameObject not the GameObject itself.

So if you need to find all Components of `Image` you need to add a Script or Component with name `Image` on your child GameObject. Naming the GameObject "Image" is not necessary.